# Cross-Origin HTTP Request originating from server-side NodeJS/Axios/JSDOM

Tags: node.js, http, cors, axios

I am using Axios to create a HTTP request to a API server in different domain.

- The API server allows Cross-Origin requests from `http://localhost:3000`.
- I have no control over the API server.
- My app usually runs in `http://localhost:3000` and makes requests from browser.

There's no problem up to this point. Cross-Origin requests are working fine. However, recently I want to add a unit test for those API calls. This test environment is `jsdom` since I'm using `Jest`. This raises a problem when I **create HTTP request from server-side**, the origin is set to `http://localhost`, which the server does not allow.

The request is made using Axios:

```
axios.post(`${API_DOMAIN}/member/account/login`, {
  username,
  password,
}, {
  headers: {
    Origin: 'http://localhost:3000'
  }
})
```

However, the response still says that

`error: Cross origin http://localhost forbidden`

How to change the "Origin" of the HTTP request I create with Axios under jsdom to other than `http://localhost`? I need it to be `http://localhost:3000` so that the API server allows me.

Answer (score 15):

It turns out `jsdom` is the one who makes the origin `localhost`, and prevented cross-origin requests. From https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1180 I was able to solve my problem. In the test suite, place this code before any HTTP requests by axios:

```
axios.defaults.adapter = require('axios/lib/adapters/http')
```

This will make Axios use NodeJS's HTTP adapter instead of JSDOM's XMLHttpRequests. This way there will be no Cross-origin problem.

Comment: You saved my day. Thanks

Comment: Worked for me , Thanks!

Comment: This worked fine. I tried adding `testEnvironment: 'node'` to my jest.config.js and that worked too

Answer (score 1):

Supplimenting @Arkross answer,

`axios/lib/adapters/http` is not exposed by the package.

Instead, you can do this:

```
axios.defaults.adapter = 'http'

// or

axios.request({
  adapter: 'http',
  ...
})
```